# Find all Hamiltonian Cycles using BFS

Tags: c++, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I know there's so many threads about this topic, but none of the ones I have found had helped me.
I have to find all the Hamiltonian cycles on a undirected graph using BFS. I have the code that search for a cycle (not hamiltonian), now I need to modify it and here's my problem. I'm not sure how to do this in a proper manner without thinking recursiverly.

My thoughts are that in order to find **all** Hamiltonian cycles using BFS I need:

- Keep a track of one possible cycle (path).
- Keep a count of the numbers of visited nodes. If I arrive to a "n" node that has the source as parent, I will need to check if all nodes are already visited.

So, in order to have a Hamiltonian Cycle, I must visit all nodes only once and finish when I arrive to a node that is inside of visited ones and that has "source" as adjacent.

Here's my graph.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/siLDn.png

And here's my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
} 
// return true if there's a cycle on the graph
bool thereIsCycle(vector<int> adj[], int s, int V)
   {
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    vector<bool> visited(V, false);

    // Set parent vertex for every vertex as -1.
    vector<int> parent(V, -1);

    // Create a queue for BFS
    queue<int> q;

    // Mark the current node as
    // visited and enqueue it
    visited[s] = true;
    q.push(s);
 
    while (!q.empty()) {
 
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
 
        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued
        // vertex u. If a adjacent has not been visited,
        // then mark it visited and enqueue it. We also
        // mark parent so that parent is not considered
        // for cycle.
        for (auto v : adj[u]) {
            if (!visited[v]) {
                visited[v] = true;
                q.push(v);
                parent[v] = u;
            }
            else if (parent[u] != v){
                return true;
            }
                
        }
    }
    return false;
}    
int main()
{
    int V = 4;
    vector<int> adj[V];
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 0);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3);
    // check if there is a cycle from node 0
    if (thereIsCycle(adj, 0, V)){
        cout << "Yes";
    }else{
        cout << "No";
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggests? Thank you all.

Comment: I have edited the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: [The](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) [unholy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [trinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) of C++.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is currently looking for simple (non-Hamiltonian) cycles in the graph. If we add to the condition `if (parent[u] != v){ return true; }` checking that all vertices have been visited (all elements of the `visited` must be true), then it looks like the code will work correctly.

Comment: Doesn't work because the code never resets `visited` back to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`addEdge` is not doing what you think it is.

1. Adj is intended to be the adjacency matrix of the graph. As implied by **matrix** this needs to be two dimensional.

2 `for (auto v : adj[u])`  makes no sense.  adj[u] is an int, so it is meaningless to 'iterate' over it.

My suggestion: Take a step back and get the fundamentals right before tackling such an advanced problem. Create an actual graph class based on a correctly implemented adjacency matrix. Test you class with something simple, say listing all reachable nodes using BFS. Once that is working you can begin to move onto bigger challenges.

Comment: `addEdge` works. `adj` doesn't passed by value, it's array (has `[]`) and passed by pointer. You can check it.

Comment: You need to decide: do you want to write C code, or do you want to use C++

Comment: `addEdge` may not be the best C+ code out there, but it is perfectly legal and working C++ code, and it does exactly what the name implies. `adj[u]` is not an `int`. There are many problems in this code but `addEdge` is not the most burning one.